# How to append and remove div on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(".sd").dblclick(function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="750" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#333" class="st">Size Chart</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="116" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">US Sizes</td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">UK sizes</td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">Foot Length (cm)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-edit">
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">17</td>
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">27</td>
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Right now If I double click on sd class it removes the whole row.
What I want to add is that when I double click on se class it adds a row .

Comment: dblclick on `.sd` should remove `tr` and dblclick on `.se` should add `tr`?

Comment: yes exactly that

Comment: You may use `$('body').on('dblclick', '.sd', function () { ... });` syntax to handle events, or bind listener to every line you will add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove `.sd` row:

```
$('body').on('dblclick', '.sd', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

To duplicate last `.se` row:

```
$('body').on('dblclick', '.se', function () {
  const $table = $(this).parents('table').first();
  let $row = $table.find('tr:has(.sd)').last();
  if ($row.size() == 0) {
    $row = $([ '<tr class="row-edit">'
             , '<td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">17</td>'
             , '<td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">27</td>'
             , '<td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">25</td>'
             , '</tr>'
             ].join('')
            );
  }
  $table.append($row.clone(true));
});
```

```js
$('body').on('dblclick', '.sd', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$('body').on('dblclick', '.se', function () {
  const $table = $(this).parents('table').first();
  let $row = $table.find('tr:has(.sd)').last();
  if ($row.size() == 0) {
    $row = $([ '<tr class="row-edit">'
             , '<td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">17</td>'
             , '<td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">27</td>'
             , '<td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">25</td>'
             , '</tr>'
             ].join('')
            );
  }
  $table.append($row.clone(true));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="750" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#333" class="st">Size Chart</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="116" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">US Sizes</td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">UK sizes</td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">Foot Length (cm)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-edit">
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">17</td>
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">27</td>
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i changed your code a little bit and it works fine, i can add a row and delete a row , you added tr as a class but it is not a class in the code

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a working solution.

```js
$(document).on("dblclick", ".sd", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
$(document).on("dblclick", ".se", function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().append(
    '<tr class="row-edit"><td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">17</td>td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">27</td><td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">25</td></tr>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="750" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#333" class="st">Size Chart</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td width="116" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">US Sizes</td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">UK sizes</td>
    <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">Foot Length (cm)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-edit">
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">17</td>
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">27</td>
    <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parent().parent().append()`

```js
$( ".sd" ).dblclick(function() {$( this ).parent().remove();});
$( ".se" ).dblclick(function() {$( this ).parent().parent().append(
            '<tr>'
            +'<td width="116" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">US Sizes</td>'
            +'<td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">15</td>'
            +'<td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">Foot Length (cm)</td>'
            +'</tr>')
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="750" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                       <tr><td colspan="3"  bgcolor="#333" class="st">Size Chart</td></tr>
                        <tr>

                        <td width="116" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">US Sizes</td>
                        <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">UK sizes</td>
                        <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">Foot Length (cm)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row-edit">
                        <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">17</td>
                        <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">27</td>
                        <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">25</td>
                        </tr> </table>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: Now you cannot delete the rows that were added

Comment: @EhteshAmAlIi happy to help :)

Comment: that is true you cannot delete the row that were added

Comment: @Gerard the OP does not ask to... if he wants just change the name of class to `sd`

Comment: @EhteshAmAlIi do you want to make the new row able to be deleted??

Comment: that issue with your answer is , I cannot remove the added row also I cannot edit the added row

Comment: @לבנימלכה it's not just a matter of changing the class name. The background color and height needs to be adjusted also. Like I said, inserting the wrong row.

Comment: @Gerard yeah i changed the code to the row i wanted to add, it adds the correct row but cannot delete the row

Comment: @לבנימלכה Answer that nicolas gave works in all cases, thanks everyone

Comment: happy to try help you any way:)

Answer (score 0):

- double click `.sd` -> delete row
- double click `.se` -> add new row

I also added the class `.sd` to the newly created row so you can delete it.

```
$(".sd").dblclick(function () {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$(".se").dblclick(function() {
  let table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.setAttribute("class", "row-edit");

  td = document.createElement("td")
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("5"));
  td.setAttribute("class", "sd");
  tr.appendChild(td);
  td = document.createElement("td")
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("123"));
  td.setAttribute("class", "sd");
  tr.appendChild(td);
  td = document.createElement("td")
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("555"));
  td.setAttribute("class", "sd");

  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

Just make sure to add an `id` to your table.

```
<table id="myTable" width="750" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

HTML

```
<table width="750" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <td colspan="3"  bgcolor="#333" class="st">Size Chart</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="116" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">US Sizes</td>
  <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">UK sizes</td>
  <td width="100" bgcolor="#FCF2E8" class="se">Foot Length (cm)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-edit">
  <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">17</td>
  <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">27</td>
  <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="sd">25</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-add" style="display:none">
  <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="add">20</td>
  <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="add">28</td>
  <td height="20" bgcolor="#FEFDF8" class="add">32</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$( ".sd" ).dblclick(function() {$(".row-add").show();});
```

So now, it add a row when I double click on a "sd" class.

Working demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpz56ycn/2/)